# Rewrite my url for generating seo friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my url for generating the seo friendly url. My original url is something like

```
video_play.php?cat=1?author=3?video=4
```

where

- `"cat=1"` is represents my category and 1 is id of my category name like song,movie etc..
- `"author=3"` 3 is the id of singer.
- `"video=4"` 4 is the id of track being played currently...

I want to make this url some thing like `video_play/song/artistname/songtitle.html`

I am trying this code in .htaccess if any one can help me.. Thanks in advance...

```
RewriteRule /author/(.*)/cate/(.*) video_play.php?author=$1&cate=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule  /author/([^\.]*)/cate/([^\.]*)  video_play.php?author=$1&cate=$2
```